# Relation between graph Laplacians and covariance matrices

Tags: graph-theory, covariance, graph-laplacian

In the "Future challenges" section of the article
*Dittrich, Thomas, and Gerald Matz. "Signal processing on signed graphs: Fundamentals and potentials." IEEE Signal Processing Magazine 37.6 (2020): 86-98*, there is the following claim: "It is folklore knowledge that graph Laplacians can be related to inverse covariance matrices". I cannot see this connection, and the article does not include any reference to support this claim. Any help regarding the connection between graph Laplacians and covariance matrices would be inmensely helpful.

Comment: I am not too familiar with graph Laplacians, but the inverses of elliptic differential operators such as the Laplacian generate covariance operators for Gaussian measures on function spaces (see Thm 3.1 of https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdr/BOOKCHAPTERS/stuart15c.pdf). It wouldn't surprise me if there is some analogue for graphs.